# How do I pass the dropdown select value to a button click in the controller and search against the value in data base?

Tags: java, html

here is the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitrule", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addruleSerch(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb") Rule obj2, ModelMap  model) {
model.addAttribute("Select", obj2.getId()); 
System.out.println("********" + obj2.getId());
ruleApi.getRule(obj2.getId());
model.addAttribute("listrule", ruleApi.getRule(obj2.getId()));
return "redirect:/hello";
}
```

here is the html....

```
<form action="/CommissionTool/submitrule" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td><select name="Select"><c:forEach items="${listRules}" var="rule">
                                    <option value="${rule.id}">
                                        <c:out value="${rule.id}" />
                                    </option>
                    </c:forEach>
                </select>
        </td>           
        <td><input type="submit" onClick="addRow('in_tbl_name')" VALUE="Add New"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

How could i fix this.. please help me
Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you need to do several changes in your code, but is pretty near.

1. You need to send the object you want to use as modelAttribute to the view the first time.
2. In your html you need to say to the form which is the object to render, your model attribute
3. Create a POST method in your controller to retrieve the object

Lets put all together in this this example. I have a class called RuleForm, which contains an attribute of type Rule.

```
public class RuleForm {
    ...
    @Getter @Setter    //here use lombok, but you could create your getters-setters methods 
    private Rule rule;
    ...
}
```

Now in the controller, into the GET method, we set the view resolver(JSP) and the object we will send to there. In this case an object of type FormRule

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitrule", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public ModelAndView addruleSerch() {
     ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("yourView");
     //here you choose the name you will use in your view, is up to you the name to choose
     model.addObject("formRule", new FormRule()); 
     return model;
}
```

Now we need to pick up that object we sent to the view and use it into our form tag.

```
<form action="/CommissionTool/submitrule" method="post" model="formRule">
...
<select name="rule.id"><c:forEach items="${listRules}" var="rule">
                                <option value="${rule.id}">
                                    <c:out value="${rule.id}" />
                                </option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
```

In this point when we send the form to the Controller, we will send the RuleForm object with a value into rule.id object, then in the controller we have to get that id value and add out business logic.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitrule", method = RequestMethod.POST)
      public String addruleSerch(@ModelAttribute RuleForm ruleForm) {
     //Here you will have access to your  object
     ruleForm.getRule().getId();// rule selected in the form
     ... your business logic 
     return "redirect:/someUrl";
}
```

Comment: @ cralfaro, still its not working, i don't need to write that post method..??

Comment: Sure i forgot to say that, let me add the response

Comment: @ cralfaro, but sir its gives an error in model.addAttribute("rule", new Rule());  how do i fix it..??

Comment: @Rezaaaa could you paste the code of your GET and POST methods?

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/submitrule", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public ModelAndView addruleSerch() {
  ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("CompPlan",  "command", new Rule());
  model.addAttribute("rule", new Rule()); 
  return model;

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/submitrule", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String addruleSerch(@ModelAttribute Rule rule) {
  //Here you will have access to your  object
  model.addAttribute("rule.id", rule.getId()); 
  System.out.println("********" + rule.getId());
  ruleApi.getRule(rule.getId());
  model.addAttribute("listrule", ruleApi.getRule(rule.getId()));
  return "redirect:/hello";
 }

Comment: @Rezaaaa i got a mistake in my response, is model.addObject("objName", new Rule()), i corrected the response

Comment: @ cralfaro which obj do i use in "objName" i don't understand sit, please help me

Comment: @Rezaaaa remember that the code i type you here is an approximation of what you really need, try to see the solution and adapt to your custom problem. The obj "objName" is the name you want to give to the object in the jsp form. You have to use the same name in the Controller and JSP, i am going to try to do a better explanation of my code so you can understand better

Comment: sir what ever you told and also i added my own logic but its seems gives an exception like java.lang.NullPointerException, i dont understand how do i fix it, i tried lot. if possible help me.. what ever controller jsp and model class i have, i already shered

Comment: @Rezaaaa where do you get the NullPointer?

Comment: @ cralfaro the value is not passed ists through exception...i am attaching the full code here ok...??

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/compplan", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView listRules(ModelMap model) {
 return new ModelAndView("CompPlan", "command", new Rule());
 
@RequestMapping(value = "/submitrule", method = RequestMethod.POST)
      public String addruleSerch(@ModelAttribute Rule obj2) {
      obj2.getRule().getId();
      ruleApi.getRule(obj2.getId());
      model.addAttribute("listrule", ruleApi.getRule(obj2.getId()));
 
  return "redirect:/compplan";
}

Comment: <form action="
/submitrule" method="post" model="formRule">
...
<select name="rule.id"><c:forEach items="${listRules}" var="rule">
                                <option>
                                    <c:out value="${rule.id}" />
                                </option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>

Comment: @ cralfaro  sir have you see my code..? is there need any correction..??

Comment: @tell me your email i will try to make you the example, you have a mix of concepts in your code...

Comment: rashid.reza_sit@yahoo.com

Comment: @ cralfaro did you get my mail id..?